# How do I learn enough about AJAX so that I know how AJAX-enabled controls are working, such that I can debug them when necessary?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, ajax

I use AJAX controls a lot - AJAX update panels, AJAX-enabled grids, etc. (mostly from Infragistics), and most of the time, things work great. But sometimes they don't, and I have no idea where to start with debugging etc. The AJAX part of it is a black box (seemingly), and I really don't like that.

I want to know enough about AJAX and javascript such that I have confidence to work with these controls instead of just praying that they work.

I want to be able to debug them, and also have confidence that I am using them properly (because I don't feel I can possibly use them really properly and appropriately if I don't know what they are doing).

What do I need to know to get this comfort? Where can I learn about this? How should I go about tackling learning about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The good/bad thing with libraries is that they abstract away the problem. Great when they work but not so useful when they don't. I'd recommend finding a learning resource on using xmlHttpRequest and work through the code examples. As @Catalin says - use Firebug to step through execution and inspect the http requests generated.

There are a lot of resources to choose from out there. One that springs to mind is:
Bulletproof Ajax by Jeremy Keith http://bulletproofajax.com/

Its quite old now but is a good explanation written for a mixed audience. The code examples are available for download from the site too.

Comment: Thanks John. Very helpful. I totally agree with the "abstract away the problem" comment. Abstracting the details is fine most of the time, but I need to know what is going on "under the hood" so I can dig into the problems when necessary. I will look at that book.

Answer (score 1):

Use firebug in firefox with the console enabled it show's you enough details.

Comment: That's a helpful suggestion. I hadn't really thought of that.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you try implementing simple versions of these controls yourself?  Im not suggesting you reimplement then - but just creating your own toy version with a few basic features (load, clear, update etc) should help you understand how the AJAX portions of these controls work.

Comment: That's a good suggestion. Any recommendations for books or links for learning this? I really don't have even a beginning understanding if AJAX.